# ImageView not being set in emulator

Tags: java, android, weather

I am trying to set a white line in Android Studio.

I have the whiteLine.png stored in drawable-hdpi. I have set it in the Main Activity. I have no idea why it is now showing in the emulator.

Tried on multiple API version, nothing changes.

Why is the whiteLine ImageView not working?

**IMAGE IN ANDROID DESIGN**

[image]

**IMAGE IN EMULATOR**

[image]

**MAIN ACTIVITY CODE**

```
whiteLine = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.whiteLine);
whiteLine.setImageResource(R.drawable.whiteline);
```

**XML**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/whiteLine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="265dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/whiteline" />
```

Comment: There are many other ways to put a white line there asides using an image.. You can manipulate the way your layouts are arranged.. I know this doesn't solve the problem though, it's just a suggestion.. I wouldn't go through this much stress for a white line.

Comment: You should post the complete `xml` layout for `MainActivity`.  Note - if all you want if a white line, then all you need is a `View` with a white background.

Comment: @MarkKeen Can you provide any docs or example of using `view` for a similar purpose?

Comment: Just in order to test if the ImageView is where you expect it to be: let it have an attribute `android:background="#ffffff"` and leave out the `app:srcCompat="@drawable/whiteline"` Then run the app.